# how can i do substraction in a loop?

Tags: c++

Hello I am learning c++ and I am doing my first exercise but I have a problem in my loop I want to do substraction but it stuck at the same number for example I want to make a fight in this exercise but the health always stuck at 93 can someone help me with this?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
class fight {
  public:
    int hero, vilian;
  void f(int h) {
    energy = h;
  }
  void k(int a) {
    ch = a;
    if (a == 1) {
      cout << "Fight";
    }
  }
  void f5(int a, int b) {
    int storage, key, p = 5;
    energy = a;
    energy1 = b;
    cout << "\nHero Energy" << a;
    cout << "\nVilian energy" << b;
    cout << "\nPress one to fight";
    do {
      cin >> key;
      storage = hero - energy1;

      cout << "\nVillian health" << storage;

      if (storage == 0) {
        break;
        cout << "\nYou won";
      }

    } while (key == 1);
  }

  private:
    int energy, energy1, ch;
};

int main() {
  fight f3;
  f3.hero = 7;
  f3.vilian = 5;
  f3.k(1);
  f3.f5(100, 100);

}
```

Comment: Please give your methods meaningful names. I don't like guessing what `k` and `f5` do :(

Comment: I'm so confused, How does this compile??? http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2686eb5d7e6d51d6

Comment: Oh, a bunch of private members are declared at the bottom. I see now.

Comment: The programmer's secret weapon is the debugger. With a debugger you can run the program on your terms, rather than the GHz of the average CPU, and watch what happens as it happens. When you see the program do something you didn't expect, you've probably found a bug.  Gather more information with the debugger, the values of the variables in use and maybe the backtrace so you can see how you got there, and then use that information to figure out how the program went off the rails. Save you tonnes of time.

Comment: This code sets both `energy` variables to 100, and then never changes them. That's probably the problem.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do, because the names are undecipherable, but you probably intended to do a `storage = hero` just before the do loop and then do `storage -= energy1` every iteration (instead of `storage = hero - energy1`)

Comment: Unrelated: I think you're limiting your game by making `fight` a class that holds `int hero, vilian;` If you turn it around to make the fighters classes (with `virtual` class specific attack methods) you'll have much more fun watching the game... I think.

Answer (score 0):

In your loop, the only variables you set are `key` and `storage`. `storage` only depend on `hero` and `energy1`, so given the formula and the values in you test you are computing `storage` to be `7 - 100` which is -93. The values for `hero` and `energy1` never changes, so `storage` never changes. IF I were to guess what you want, you want to set `storage` to be be `energy1` and deplete it by `hero` at every iteration of the loop. Once that goes *below* zero, you end the game:

```
storage = energy1;
do {
  cin >> key;
  storage = storage - hero;

  cout << "\nVillian health" << storage;

  // Note this is an inequality, 7 is not divisible by 100
  // so storage will never be exactly 0.
  if (storage <= 0) { 
    break;
    cout << "\nYou won";
  }

} while (key == 1);
```

Comment: Thank you very much it worked but can you explain why it didn't work with my code why the number doesn't change with my way and why should I do this storage =storage - hero?